# Need to concat two ffmpeg commands

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

First command - add watermark to my video:

```
"-y", "-i", videoUrl, "-strict", "experimental", "-vf", "movie=" + watermarkImagePath + "[watermark];[in][watermark]overlay=15:main_h-overlay_h[out]", "-s", "360*480", "-r", "20", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", outputVideoUrl
```

Second command - concat other video along with watermarked video (first command video as input):

```
"-i",inputFile1,"-i",inputFile2,"-v","debug","-strict”,”-2”,”-filter_complex","[0:v][0:a:0][1:v][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]","-map","[v]","-map","[a]",outUrl
```

Please help on merging this as single command.

Answer (score 1):

Connect separate filterchains with a semicolon (`;`).

```
ffmpeg -i video0 -i video1 -i image -filter_complex
  "[0:v][2:v]overlay=15:main_h-overlay_h[over];
   [over][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output
```

No need for the movie source filter. Just add your overlay image as a normal input.